# Adding row to numpy recarray

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an easy way to add a record/row to a numpy recarray without creating a new recarray? Let's say I have a recarray that takes 1Gb in memory, I want to be able to add a row to it without having python take up 2Gb of memory temporarily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call [`yourrecarray.resize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.resize.html#numpy.recarray.resize) with a shape which has one more row, then assign to that new row.  Of course. `numpy` *might* still have to allocate completely new memory if it just doesn't have room to grow the array in-place, but at least you stand a chance!-)

Since an example was requested, here comes, modified off the canonical [example list](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List)...:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> mydescriptor = {'names': ('gender','age','weight'), 'formats': ('S1', 'f4', 'f4')} 
>>> a = numpy.array([('M',64.0,75.0),('F',25.0,60.0)], dtype=mydescriptor)
>>> print a
[('M', 64.0, 75.0) ('F', 25.0, 60.0)]
>>> a.shape
(2,)
>>> a.resize(3)
>>> a.shape
(3,)
>>> print a
[('M', 64.0, 75.0) ('F', 25.0, 60.0) ('', 0.0, 0.0)]
>>> a[2] = ('X', 17.0, 61.5)
>>> print a
[('M', 64.0, 75.0) ('F', 25.0, 60.0) ('X', 17.0, 61.5)]
```

Comment: Could you show some demonstration code? My attempt at calling arr.resize() ended with
ValueError: cannot resize this array:  it does not own its data

Comment: @unutbu, sure, edited answer to supply simple example.  You may be meeting issues discussed in this thread: http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Mail/Message/numpy-discussion/3042521 -- then you can fix them, as Travis Oliphant mentions there, by adding the refcheck=0 argument to the resize call (unless you HAVE shared the data, in which case there can be no resizing in-place any more (note that what Travis mentions as a feature of the SVN head of numpy has been part of regularly released numpy for a long time by now -- that thread is 3+ years old;-).

Comment: I wish the numpy's developers had thought of a better way to add a row to a dataset. It is a very common operation and I don't understand why it should be so inefficient.